# How to fill a table with data from service in Angular Material?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, web-services, mat-table

I'm trying to create a table with information returned from a service. The problem is that the only row shown is the last one in the list returned by the service.

Code from `list.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DepartamentoService } from '../../_service/departamento.service';

export interface Items{
   idItem: number;
   nameItem: string;
}

@Component({
   selector: 'app-list',
   templateUrl: './list.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

     displayedColumns: string[] = ['idItem', 'nameItem', 'options'];
     columnsToDisplay: string[] = this.displayedColumns.slice();
     itemList: Items[];
     
     constructor(private itemService: ItemsService) { }

     ngOnInit(): void {
            this.itemService.list().subscribe(data => {
            data.forEach(element => {
                this.itemList = [{idItem: element.idItem, nameItem: element.nameItem}];
                console.log(`Id: ${element.idItem} - Name ${element.nameItem}`);
         });
     });
 }
}
```

Code from `list.component.html`

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="itemList" class="mat-elevation-z8">
     <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
         <th id="head" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
     </ng-container>

     <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
     <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></tr>
</table>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is depList ?

Comment: @pc_coder  yes I edited the question with the correct variable name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/dlxbkjqaoba?file=app/table-basic-example.ts) Firstly I saw here

```
 displayedColumns: string[] = ['idItem', 'name', 'options'];
```

and Items interface is ummatched. change name to nameItem

```
 displayedColumns: string[] = ['idItem', 'nameItem', 'options'];
```

another part is that you need to push it rather that assign

```
this.itemList.push({idItem: element.idItem, nameItem: element.nameItem};
```

and don't forget to initialize your itemList in constructor or ngOnInit life cycle.

```
this.itemList=[];
```

Comment: I followed your suggestions, but the data is not showing in the table. I printed the array in `console.log ()` to see if the data is being saved to the array. I don't know if it is something with the table because the array is storing the data correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the value in the wrong way to the itemList variable.
You're doing:

```
this.itemList = [{idItem: element.idItem, nameItem: element.nameItem}];
```

What's wrong with this is that every iteration of the loop you're re-assigning only one row to the itemList variable, you need to push each a value each iteration in order to show all of the rows.

You need to do this:

```
this.itemList.push({idItem: element.idItem, nameItem: element.nameItem};
```

Be sure to declare item list this way:

```
itemList: any[] = []; // add a empty array as first value to be able to use the push() method
```

Comment: I followed your suggestions, but the data is not showing in the table. The array correctly stores the information, but nothing is displayed in the table.

Answer (score 0):

The information provided in the answers works, but I had to add another step:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

 displayedColumns: string[] = ['idItem', 'nameItem', 'options'];
 columnsToDisplay: string[] = this.displayedColumns.slice();
 itemList: Items[];
 dataSource = []; // create a new array
 
 constructor(private itemService: ItemsService) { }

 ngOnInit(): void {
        this.itemService.list().subscribe(data => {
        data.forEach(element => {
            this.itemList = [{idItem: element.idItem, nameItem: element.nameItem}];
            console.log(`Id: ${element.idItem} - Name ${element.nameItem}`);
     });
     this.dataSource = this.itemList; // assign the array with the data to the new one
 });
}
```

You must change the source of the data in the table with the name of the new array:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
```